# vscode-test - error when calling runTests

Tags: typescript, testing, visual-studio-code

Its the first time im trying to set up tests for my vscode extension.

I basically just copy pasted the example from /working-with-extensions/testing-extension from code.visualstudio.

I can't call runTests because of the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ extensionDevelopmentPath: string; extensionTestsPath: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestOptions | ExplicitTestOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extensionDevelopmentPath' does not exist in type 'TestOptions | ExplicitTestOptions'.
```

and that's my code:

```
import * as path from 'path';

import { runTests } from 'vscode-test';


async function main() {
    try {
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../');

        const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index');

        await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath });

    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests.');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}


main();
```

I can't find a mistake and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: have you look at runTests definition? as error said there is no extensionDevelopmentPath

Comment: I checked the code on GitHub under microsoft/vscode-test/lib/runTest.ts. There are extensionDevelopmentPath and extensionTestsPath. But I checked the definition in my editor now, and changed it to extensionPath and testRunnerPath. I should've checked that before, thanks.

Comment: yeah, old documentation

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is [currently](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/blob/master/lib/runTest.ts) :

```
async function main() {
    try {
        let testOption = { extensionDevelopmentPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'), extensionTestsPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index') };
        // Download VS Code, unzip it and run the integration test
        await runTests(testOption);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
```